# Why do I see words when I press shift+esc on Chrome address bar?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

This list of words also appears when I put a textbox on a PDF when opened in Preview and press Esc. I suspect this has nothing to do with Chrome.

[image: shift+esc pressed]

Answer (score 1):

That is normal, I think this was added when yosemite was released. Its basically predictive text for the mac. That shows up every time you press the esc key in a textfield. Hope this helps :)

Comment: How do you use the predictive text? Is there documentation somewhere?

Comment: Here is a link on how to use predictive text http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/10/25/using-predictive-text-in-os-x-yosemite/